# Doctrine Out of Memory in Entity with to much entities in ManyToMany connection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have a memory issue with getting the collection of entities - Attachments. I am using PHP7.4, Symfony 5.4, Doctrine 2.7.5, APIPlatform 2.7

Class `Attachment` have this field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Message", inversedBy="attachment")
 */
private Collection $messages;
```

With classic getters and setters.

in my QueryCollectionExtension in Doctrine, ApiPlatform I have added:

```
private function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass): void
    $queryBuilder
        ->andWhere('a.messages is not empty')
// breaks when preparing to execute this query
```

Then I get this error

```
Error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 249856 bytes)" at /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php line 138 
{"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\OutOfMemoryError(code: 0)
```

My suspicion is that there are **attachments that are sent in thousands of messages**. when you try to access those attachments, you get an Entity with thousands of `Message` entities in `$attachment->getMessages()`

And that in a query where it breaks looks like this:

```
AND (
            SELECT
              COUNT(*)
            FROM
              attachment_message p4_
            WHERE
              p4_.attachment_id = p2_.id
          ) > ?
```

Without that part, the query runs slowly, but without any problem.

**Does anyone have some solution on how to optimize this without restructuring entities?**

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory and the memory limit? The error message tells you how much was missing. Rinse and repeat then you don't have to restructure entities which seems somewhat important to you. You could also try process a smaller amount of messages, but going with more memory is generally cheaper and faster. And everything else would require metrics and reports, so don't work well with guesses like _"My suspicion is that there are attachments that are sent in thousands of messages."_, just handle the memory error from an operational perspective first.

Comment: @hakre Buying RAM on servers is much more expensive than optimizing queries. PHP currently on production servers can use 16GB of RAM out of 32 GB. Your suggestion is to increase memory. Let's say for example we increase it to 64GB, and we have 5 servers, that's 5x32GB. That's a couple of hundred dollars per month. And again that's just a temporary solution until the number of messages increases more.  The answer to my question that solved my issue can be found below.

Comment: Yes, sure, it's just has been that you wrote you didn't want to restructure, but that is otherwise likely necessary. So a bit pushing the boundaries. In practice, increasing the memory for two weeks can just be the thing that buys you enough time to find the sweet spot of fix that decrease then memory consumption by 4 and higher. Requires metrics which then again may need additional memory to be effective. 16GB for PHP IMHO is much too high. Sounds like a passed chance and re-introducing lower limits can then hurt. But it's perhaps worth to go through some pain and add clinic constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine can't cover every use case for you out of the box. Especially when you have huge amount of data in many-to-many relationship.

But you can solve the problem by self. There are several methods to do so. And also you need to optimize your DB, if you haven't done it yet. For example, you need indexes on `attachment_id` and `message_id`. I hope Doctrine generated them in migrations but it's better to check just in case.

Some possible solutions:

1. Limit Hydration: instead of fully hydrating entities, consider using partial hydration or even a select to only fetch the columns you actually need. This can save a lot of memory when dealing with large collections.
2. Use the `getArrayResult()` method instead of getResult(). This will give you arrays instead of objects, which can be more memory efficient.
3. Use pagination. Do you really need all the data at this point?
4. And the most flexible solution — use native queries. You can set up own hydration for native query to fill the entities with data. For example you can use query like this:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM attachment a
INNER JOIN attachment_message am ON a.id = am.attachment_id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(am.message_id) > 0
```

It will not fetch messages at all, just attachments.

Comment: This is a great set of instructions on how to optimize any legacy project, especially for a project like this one. Numbers 1 and 2 helped in this case.  3 and 4 are great as future improvements. Thanks!